# Apache localhost file browser

Tags: apache, directory, localhost

When I type in my browser `http://localhost` why does it open up whatever is named index.html?

If instead, I remove the index.html from my local drive hooked up to Apache, then when I type `http://localhost` again in my browser, this time it opens up a tree like file structure ("Index of/") page.

Are these default settings and how can I change them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Apache indexes any file with the name "Index" or "default" 
& Yes you can change those using `.htaccess` file

Open Notepad and type:

```
DirectoryIndex Home.html
```

Save it as .htaccess extension (without name) in `C:\wamp\www\`

As you see we set the file Home.html to be indexed instead of i.e. `index.php`, `default.php` or `index.html`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I forgot to mention I'm working under OSX